# Combining google sheet form responses into a description for google calendar event

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm new to scripting and have been trying to put this together without having to purchase an extension or use a chrome add-on.

I want to be able to take not only Goggle script form responses, but also extra columns of the form responses' spreadsheet (where I have manipulated some of the responses in a different column) and use that to set a calendar appointment in which the description is the column(s) of manipulated data (not an original response column of data).  In the example below, I want the calendar description to be the column [Combo Description] that represents an arrayformula combination of two form responses: [Event Description] and [New Description], which upon each form response appears in the defined calendar.

Here's an example I'm trying to modified is a simplified version of something more detailed I'm attempting to do.

My example form is here 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1EcafKYmstMiPcIhYpEsnvmf47yyeWNiYZIyxr93QkPU/edit?usp=sharing

The supporting google spreadsheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1db6n-d88KrCWKXMuaFYYOU75pNOAysqwBuc7aORkmKE/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using a modified version of a script from the following website:
http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event

Here's a copy of my/his script:

```
//Load the Moment.js library once.
var moment = Moment.load();

  var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : "1EcafKYmstMiPcIhYpEsnvmf47yyeWNiYZIyxr93QkPU",  

  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "81hoju2sgoldcjom4888opngk0@group.calendar.google.com",


  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Event Title",
    startTime : "Event Date and Start Time",
    endTime: "Event Date and End Time",
    description: "Event Description",  // Tried the following: + , & concate col[6]:which didn't throw an error but didn't make an appointment either
    location: "Event Location",
    email: "Add Guests",
  },
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1], // The -1 goes after length 
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses()  // Took a comma off here
      //create an empty object to store data from the last 
      //form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
    } 
  }
  return eventObject;
}

function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.title,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created
      endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();  
      //an options object containing the description and guest list
  //for the event that will be created
  var options = {
    description : eventObject.description,
    guests : eventObject.email,
    location: eventObject.location,
  };
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                     endTime, options)
    } catch (e) {
      //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
      //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
      //throw an error.
      delete options.guests
      //create the event without including the guest
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                       endTime, options)
      }
  return event;   
  Logger.log(event);
}



/*** 
For later to make the endDate be a fixed 2hr appointment
var submittedDate = new Date(userSubmission);
var parsedDate = Date.parse(submittedDate); 
var endDate = new Date(parsedDate + 120000); 
**/
```

Please any hints or suggestions to how to get the extra columns of the form spreadsheet into the calendar suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: A much simpler way to access the latest form response is to capture the event object directly, i.e. `onFormSubmit(e)` - the [`e` variable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) is very useful. Also review the Spreadsheet reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, since you just combine the `New Description` and `Event Description` items to create a new description. You don't need to use an array formula and google sheets to combine it. You can do it in the app script itself.

**Modification:**
1) You will have to retrieve this new item (New Description) from the form. You will modify your formmap object, to include this new item

```
formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Event Title",
    startTime : "Event Date and Start Time",
    endTime: "Event Date and End Time",
    description: "Event Description",  // Tried the following: + , & concate col[6]:which didn't throw an error but didn't make an appointment either
    location: "Event Location",
    email: "Add Guests",
    newdescription : "New Description"  //New entery
  }
```

2) You will obtain the new entry made by the user in switch case statement like so:

```
switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.newdescription: 
        eventObject.newdescription = thisResponse; //New description entry
        break;
    }
```

3) Then to make the combo description you just join the strings description and newdescription.

```
var comboDescription = eventObject.description+" "+eventObject.newdescription
```

And use this new comboDescription to create your calendar event.

```
var comboDescription = eventObject.description+" "+eventObject.newdescription
var options = {
    description : comboDescription,
    guests : eventObject.email,
    location: eventObject.location,
  };
```

Once you make all these modifications, your final code will be:

```
var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : "1EcafKYmstMiPcIhYpEsnvmf47yyeWNiYZIyxr93QkPU",  

  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "81hoju2sgoldcjom4888opngk0@group.calendar.google.com",


  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Event Title",
    startTime : "Event Date and Start Time",
    endTime: "Event Date and End Time",
    description: "Event Description",  // Tried the following: + , & concate col[6]:which didn't throw an error but didn't make an appointment either
    location: "Event Location",
    email: "Add Guests",
    newdescription : "New Description"  //New entery
  },
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1], // The -1 goes after length 
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses()  // Took a comma off here
      //create an empty object to store data from the last 
      //form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.location:
        eventObject.location = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.newdescription: 
        eventObject.newdescription = thisResponse; //New description entry
        break;
    } 
  }
  return eventObject;
}

function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.title,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created
      endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();  
      //an options object containing the description and guest list
  //for the event that will be created
    var comboDescription = eventObject.description+" "+eventObject.newdescription
    var options = {
        description : comboDescription,
        guests : eventObject.email,
        location: eventObject.location,
      };
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                     endTime, options)
    } catch (e) {
      //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
      //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
      //throw an error.
      delete options.guests
      //create the event without including the guest
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                       endTime, options)
      }
  return event;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply!  Your solution wasn't what I had in mind, but it works for this simple form!  In general is there a way to include a column from the response spreadsheet that was not created by a response question.  The arrayformula combination for the description was just a simple example.   In truth, I want to be able to query other sheets in the extra column for data and then incorporate that extra column of data into the description that feeds into the calendar.

Comment: Most of the time you should be able to modify the form data with the app script and not need to use a formula in google sheet. However, you can indeed query a sheet to get your data.I am assuming, currently the above script is bound to a form, I would modify the script such that it is bound to a google sheet. And use spreadsheets onFormSubmit(e) trigger and use the event object (e in this case)to determine the form entries and row number. Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)